# Pure C - Passing the reference of a pointer of a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have created a program that is loading a database with student information from the keyboard, after that I am trying to create an option to add a new registration of a student to that database

the struct consists of

```
typedef struct {
    long unsigned int aem;
    char name[64];
    short unsigned int lessonsToPass;
} Registration;
```

I have created a pointer of it on the main function

```
int i, sizeOfDatabase;
Registration *database
scanf("%d", &sizeOfDatabase);
database = (Registration*) malloc(sizeOfDatabase * sizeof(Registration));
for(i = 0; i < sizeOfDatabase; ++i){
    scanf("%lu%63s%hu", &(database+i)->aem, (database+i)->name, &(database+i)->lessonsToPass);
    for(tmp = (database+i)->name; (*tmp=toupper(*tmp)); ++tmp);
}
```

So basically I am getting the database from the keyboard and making the name to uppercase

after that I am calling a function to add a new registration

```
void add(char *aem, char *name, char *lessonsToPass, int currentDatabaseSize, Registration **database){
    char *tmp;
    int newSize = currentDatabaseSize + 1;
    *database = (Registration*) realloc(*database, newSize * sizeof(Registration));
    for(tmp = name; (*tmp=toupper(*tmp)); ++tmp);
    (*database + newSize)->aem = atoi(aem);
    strcpy((*database + newSize)->name, name);
    (*database + newSize)->lessonsToPass = atoi(lessonsToPass);
}
```

the char *name  is never bigger than 64 and I am still getting compilation error `malloc(): corrupted top size`

What am I missing?

Comment: Please get out of the habit of writing things like `(database+i)->aem`. It's more idiomatic to write `database[i].aem`.

Comment: @Barmar but database is not an array

Comment: @xing Wwhy? since `newSize` is bigger than the `sizeOfDatabase` what am I understanding wrong?

Comment: @xing I see so it is supposed to be `newSize - 1`? Which is actually the `sizeOfDatabase`?

Comment: @KarampistisDimitrios `database` is a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array of `Registration` structures. You can use array notation to access the elements, and it makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(*database + newSize)->aem = atoi(aem);
```

Just wrote off the allocated block because `newSize` contains the number of allocated records including the one being created now. Correct code:

```
(*database + newSize - 1)->aem = atoi(aem);
strcpy((*database + newSize - 1)->name, name);
(*database + newSize - 1)->lessonsToPass = atoi(lessonsToPass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen some unusual idioms to represent what you're trying to do. Here's code that's more understandable and fixes the problem. Note I'm assuming you have a modern C compiler. The style of your code is C89. That's 1989.  If it's an option, you should be using newer C language features.

First make a string uppercase method to prevent duplicate code:

```
void strtoupper(char *s) {
  for (char *p = s; *p; ++p) *p = toupper(*p);
}
```

Now the rest:

```
int sizeOfDatabase;
Registration *database;

scanf("%d", &sizeOfDatabase);
database = malloc(sizeOfDatabase * sizeof *database); // NO CAST HERE!
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfDatabase; ++i){
  Registration *r = database + i;
  scanf("%lu%63s%hu", &r->aem, r->name, &r->lessonsToPass);
  strtouper(r->name);
}
```

You should pass a *pointer* to the database size so the `add` method can update it. While calling `realloc` the way you do is correct, it's inefficient because every call requires time proportional to the entire database size. If it ever got big, you'd regret this. But that's a fine point we'll ignore.

```
void add(char *aem, char *name, char *lessonsToPass,
  Registration **database, int *dbSize) {
  int i = (*dbSize)++; // Increase db size by 1 and get new element's index.
  Registration *db = *database = realloc(*database, *dbSize * sizeof **database);
  Registration *r = db + i;
  strcpy(r->name, name);  // DON'T MODIFY THE INPUT.
  strtoupper(r->name);
  r->aem = atoi(aem);
  r->lessonsToPass = atoi(lessonsToPass);
}
```

I hope this makes sense.